# Is generating random numbers from hardware performance cryptographically secure?

Tags: random, hash, cryptography, benchmarking, hardware

Suppose I have a program that needs an RNG.

If I were to run arbitrary operations and check the ∆t it takes to do said operations, I could generate random numbers from that

For example:

```
double start = device.time();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++);//assume compiler doesn't optimize this away
double end = device.time();
double dt = end-start;
```

dt will be more or less random based on many variables on the device such as battery level, transistor age, room temperature, other processes running, etc.

Now, suppose I keep generating `dt`s and multiply them together as I go, hundreds of times, thousands of times, millions of times, eventually I am left with a very arbitrary number based on values that were more or less randomly calculated by hardware performance benchmarking.

Every time I multiply these `dt`s together, the possible outputs increases exponentially, so determining what possible outputs may be becomes perhaps an impossible task after millions of iterations of this, even if each individual `dt` value is going to be within a similar range.

---

A thought then occurs, if you have a very consistent device, you may have `dt` always in the range of say `0.000000011, 0.000000012, 0.000000013, 0.000000014`, then the final output number, no matter how many times I iterate and multiply, will be a number of the form `0.000000011^a * 0.000000012^b * 0.000000013^c * 0.000000014^d`, that's probably easy to crack.

But then I turn to hashing, suppose rather than multiplying each dt, I concatenate it in string form to the previous values and hash them, so every time I generate a new dt based on hardware performance's random environmental values, I hash. Then at the end I digest the hash to whatever form I need, now the final output number can't be written in a general algebraic form.

Will numbers generated in this form be cryptographically secure?

Comment: Nobody knows. That's basically what is done today for most platform cryptographic randomizers, not multiplying them but hashing them. Are they any good? Most people think so, but none can prove it. By the way, taking the difference is valuable for estimating the entropy, but the tuple (time before, time after) contains at least as much entropy as their difference, so just hash the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Using a clock potentially leaks information to an adversary.  Using a microphone also -- the adversary may have planted a bug and is hearing the same input.  Best not to rely on any single source but to combine entropy inputs from multiple sources, both external to your computer and internal.  By all means use internal OS entropy sources, such as dev/urandom, but use other sources as well.

It might be worth reading the description of the [Fortuna CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you take enough samples, and use few enough low bits of the time difference, then maybe timing of async interrupts could eventually add up to a useful amount of entropy.

Most OS kernels will collect entropy from timing in their own interrupt handlers, as part of the source for `/dev/urandom`, but if you really want to roll your own instead of asking the OS for randomness, it's plausible if you're very careful with your mixing function.  e.g. have a look at what the Linux kernel uses for mixing in new data into its entropy pool.  It has to avoid being "hurt" by sources that aren't actually random on a given system.

**Other than interrupts, performance over short times is nearly deterministic, and CPU frequency variations are quantized into not that many different frequencies.**

> based on many variables on the device such as ...

- *battery level*: maybe a 2-state effect like limiting max turbo when not on AC power, and/or when the battery is low.
- *transistor age*: no.  At most an indirect effect if aged transistors use more power, leading to the CPU running hotter and dropping out of max turbo sooner.  I'm not sure there's any significant effect.
- *room temperature*: again, only possibly reducing max clock speed sooner.  Unless you're wasting multiple seconds of CPU time on this, it won't have an effect even on lightweight laptops.  Desktops typically have enough cooling to sustain max turbo indefinitely on a single core, especially for simple scalar code.  (SIMD FMA would make a lot more heat.)
- *other processes running*: yes, that and async interrupts that happen to come inside your timed intervals will be the main source of randomness.

**Most of the factors that affect clock speed will just uniformly scale up all times, correlated between samples, not more entropy.**  Clock frequency doesn't change that often; after ramping up to full speed for your benchmark loops, expect it to stay constant for multiple seconds.